# Javascript: adding dynamic method

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, dynamic, methods

I got the following problem.

I have different object like:

user with the method : id, username, firstname, lastname 
article :with some other method;

i want to add dynamic method like getById, getByUsername etc.

```
var object = new Object() ; // Object can take the value user, article or other. </code>
for(var key in object) {
this["getBy" + key]= function(args) {  
    var result = query("SELECT * FROM " + object.name + ' WHERE ' key + "=" +args);
    console.log(key); //always return the last key of object
    return(result);
}

// then

var user = new User();
user.getByUsername('someone');
```

The dynamic add of method like this works fine when there is no argument in the function. All the method are well define but when I call them key as change (of course) to I just have the last function.

If someone can help me, I spend all my day on this, and I still can't find a solution.

Comment: could you precise how you call the functions ?

Comment: btw, could you provide details about the `user` object ?

Comment: Your question seems not clear because your code is incomplete, what `this` refers to ? `user` object, but intuively, what seems to happen is that each key in your loop must override its precedent

Comment: As is written, `this` in your code currently refer to the global (or in node, the module global) object. Or it may even refer to null in the case of ES5 strict mode. Since `this` in javascript depends on how the surrounding code gets executed you need to provide the code for that as well - is it a constructor? A callback? An event handler?

Comment: your approach of `SELECT` is difficult and not maintainable, usually there are standard methods on an `User`,`Article` as entities of a database, you build more difficult `SELECT` by building a query and not building a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem, when I was calling the function ByX the value of key was the last one in my object. So I put the function in a closure. But inside the closure this didn't refer to find but a general object.

So I just pass this inside my closure.

```
for(var key in Object){
    var query = 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE ' + key + "=\'";

        (function(insideQuery, obj){
            console.log(obj);
            addMethod("By"+key, obj, function(args) {

                    insideQuery+= args + "\'";
                    console.log(insideQuery);
                    return(connection.query(insideQuery));
                });

        })(query, this);
    }


function addMethod(key, obj,  fn){
  obj[key] = fn;
}
```

And it's doing exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
var User = function(id, username, firstname, lastname) {
               this.name = 'user';
               this.id = id; 
               this.username = username;
               this.firstname = firstname; 
               this. lastname = lastname;
           };



var Find = function(objectName){

               var object = new objectName();

               // I have a first method all 
               // this refers to find object
               this.all = connection.query("SELECT * FROM " + objectName);


               //then I want to add ByX method, X taking the values id, username ...

               for( key in object ) {
                   if(key != "name") { // I exclude name method of user

                       var query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE " + key + "=" ; 

                       this['By'+key] =  function(args) {
                           query += args;
                           return(connection.query(query);
                      };

               }



// then In my code

var find = new Find('User');
var list = find.ByX(something);
    list
        .on("error", function(err){
            console.log(err);
        })
        .on('result' function(row){
            console.log(row);
        })
   ;
```

when the code is compiled object Find have methods ByX, but when I run 
    find.ByX(something);

the key passed to last value it occurs to be lastname. and it's run

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE " + key + "=" ;
function(args) { 
        query += args; // query is recalculated and key is now lastname;
        ...
}
```

I did it in this way somewhere else in my code but it seems because the function is waiting for args value, the query is not set.